# Композиция из java-приложений

Tags: java, java-ee, maven

Доброго времени суток всем! Возникли интересные вопросы, на которые ответить у меня не хватит профессионального опыта. Поэтому обращаюсь к более опытным гуру.

Есть идея в создании централизованного веб-приложения, и прикрепляемым к нему n-ое кол-во платформ (можно сказать, тоже веб-приложения). Само собой, отдельные приложения будут работать на отдельных машинах (и иметь свои базы данных), но успешно взаимодействовать между собой.

Вопросы в следующем:
1. Как вести разработку данного "зоопарка"? Использовать как отдельные maven-приложения, или делать как единый проект, но с разграничением (родитель-дочерние). Либо есть какие-то другие способы?
2. Как не запутаться с VCS (гит, или меркуриал, не важно). Вести разработку в общем репозитории, или в отдельных.
3. Какую литературу можно почитать, дабы облегчить себе разработку?

Если у кого был опыт в разработке нечто подобных систем - поделитесь, пожалуйста!

Comment: 1. как минимум одно приложение = один проект, в последствии возможно проекты могут бить на подпроекты/модули.. 2. один проект = один vcs и никакой путаницы